# How can I await an async method without an async modifier in this parent method?

Tags: c#, .net-4.5, async-await

I have a method that I want to await but I don't want to cause a domino effect thinking anything can call this calling method and await it.  For example, I have this method:

```
public bool Save(string data)
{
   int rowsAffected = await UpdateDataAsync(data);
   return rowsAffected > 0;
}
```

I'm calling:

```
public Task<int> UpdateDataAsync()
{
  return Task.Run(() =>
  {
    return Data.Update(); //return an integer of rowsAffected
  }
}
```

This won't work because I have to put "async" in the method signature for `Save()` and then I can't return `bool` I have to make it `Task<bool>` but I don't want anyone awaiting the `Save()` method.

Is there a way I can suspend the code execution like await or somehow await this code without the async modifier?

Comment: I would be pretty annoyed if you gave me access to a `Save` method that blocked my thread, thus forcing me to wrap the call in a `Task`, which is exactly what you could have returned me in the first place. Just saying.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> How can I await an async method without an async modifier in this parent method?

That's kind of like asking "how can I write an application using C# but without taking a dependency on any kind of .NET runtime?"

Short answer: don't do that.

Really, what you're doing here is taking a naturally-synchronous method (`Update`), making it appear asynchronous by running it on a thread pool thread (`UpdateDataAsync`), and then you're wanting to block on it to make the asynchronous method appear synchronous (`Save`). Serious red flags.

I recommend you carefully study Stephen Toub's famous pair of blog posts [should I expose asynchronous wrappers for my synchronous methods](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/should-i-expose-asynchronous-wrappers-for-synchronous-methods/) and [should I expose synchronous wrappers for my asynchronous methods](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/should-i-expose-synchronous-wrappers-for-asynchronous-methods/). The answer to both questions is "no", though Stephen Toub explains several options to do it if you really have to.

That "really have to" should be reserved for the application level. I assume these methods (`Update`, `UpdateDataAsync`, and `Save`) are in different layers of the application (e.g., data / data service / view model). The data / data service layers should not be doing synchronous/asynchronous conversions. The view model (application-specific) level is the only one that has an excuse to do that kind of conversion -- and it should only do so as a last resort.

Comment: What if I'm writing a test case where I put stuff in a database (with an Async driver) and then immediately read it back out? Just saying, there are legitimate use cases for synchronous programming.

Comment: @Hypershadsy: Why couldn't you do it asynchronously?

Comment: You can write async test cases?

Comment: @Hypershadsy: Yes. All the major unit test frameworks (xUnit, MSTest, NUnit) have supported `async Task` unit test methods [since 2012](https://github.com/StephenCleary/Presentations/tree/master/Async%20Unit%20Testing).

Answer (score 12):

Edit: this answer was before the Task.Run was added. With that extra context, the scenario is best described as "don't do that".

---

You can access `.Result` or use `.Wait()`, but you need to know how the task is implemented first. In particular, you need to know whether it uses sync-context. The reason this is important is that if it does this could deadlock immediately, because some sync-contexts need the calling context to exit *completely* (for example, MVC's sync-context needs to leave the controller's action method).

To guard against this is hard, but you should probably always explicitly specify a timeout with a call to `.Wait()` - just in case.

Comment: Thank you, I'm using Task.Run - I updated my question to show the second method

Comment: @Neal with the edit, I would say just "don't do that" - you are adding a thread for no reason whatsoever. You might as well do that work on the thread that is going to be sat waiting.

Comment: @Neal: Marc is absolutely right; essentially what you are doing here is hiring someone to wait on your behalf, and then waiting until they're done their job, which is waiting on your behalf. You wouldn't hire someone to do that in real life, so don't do it here. If you need to wait synchronously for the task to be done then do so; if you want to keep on doing work while you're waiting then `await` it.