# How to properly catch asynchronous task?

Tags: c#, async-await, try-catch

I was wondering why the exception in this `Click` event is not being caught?  Nothing fancy in the code, except for `statusLabel` displaying the status of the process to the user.  `myDataTable` is a local variable; the goal is to assign the result to it.

Does `GetDataTable` have to be asynchronous as well?

```
public DataTable GetDataTable(string connectionString, string cmdText)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {
        using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(cmdText, conn)) {
            conn.Open();
            dt.Load(comm.ExecuteReader);
            return dt;
        }
    }
}

private async void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try {
        statusLabel.Text = "Processing...";

        Task<DataTable> dtTask = Task.Run(() => GetDataTable(connectionString, commandText));
        await dtTask;
        myDataTable = dtTask.Result;

        statusLabel.Text = "Done!";
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        MessageBox.Show("Error");
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I managed to do solve this problem by making `GetDataTable()` return a `Task` of `DataTable` and changing both `.Open` and `.ExecuteReader` to their asynchronous counterparts.  For the other method, those three lines inside the `Try` block I reduced to one:

```
myDataTable = await GetDataTable(connectionString, commandText);
```

Thanks to everyone's patiences!

Comment: You are using the Result property .. might as well not use a Task ..

Comment: I'm assuming the problem is using await on a non async method. I can analyse exactly what is going on (hence a comment and not an answer). You can remove that line completely or use GetAwaiter().GetResult() instead of that line and the following one. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16877262/how-can-i-await-an-async-method-without-an-async-modifier-in-this-parent-method and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17284517/is-task-result-the-same-as-getawaiter-getresult

Comment: Or as G-Man says don't even use a task if you are waiting synchronously for the result.

Comment: also instead of using ExecuteReader, if you are looking for an async operation, use SqlCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh204836(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I'm trying to make it asynchronous, because `GetDataTable()` can take very long and block the UI.  I'm trying to avoid this. :(

Comment: @G-Man, he's awaiting `dtTask` before assigning `myDataTable = dtTask.Result`, though. So it's still async. Essentially the same thing as `myDataTable = await dtTask`.

Comment: @IIian not pretty..

Comment: I know. Just commenting that it's not synchronously waiting for the result (as others have commented within the thread).

Comment: Setting the await-async bit for a moment, how can I make the code enter the catch block when the exception occurs at the `GetDataTable()` side? (e.g. connection login failed, database/table does not exist)  Thanks! :)

Comment: @AwonDanag I can't reproduce your problem in my test code. Are you certain that `GetDataTable()` is throwing an exception or that you're not swallowing it? What happens if, for testing purposes, you replace the contents of `GetDataTable()` to just throw an exception?

Comment: @IlianPinzon If I did it right, it just says 'An exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in Class1.dll but was not handled in user code'.  I should add that `GetDataTable()` is just referenced from a separate project, and is actually `Public Shared`.

Comment: @AwonDanag: When posting a question about an exception, please include the exception type, message, and stack trace in the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `Task.Run` to convert a synchronous method to an asynchronous one, use `ExecuteReaderAsync` to *truly* load data asynchronously. After that, your code becomes a lot simpler:

```
public async Task<DataTable> GetDataTable(string connectionString, string cmdText)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {
        using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(cmdText, conn)) {
            conn.Open();
            var reader=await comm.ExecuteReaderAsync();
            dt.Load(reader);
            return dt;
        }
    }
}

private async void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try {
        statusLabel.Text = "Processing...";

        myDataTable = await GetDataTable(connectionString, commandText);

        statusLabel.Text = "Done!";
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        MessageBox.Show("Error");
    }
}
```

`GetDataTable` became an asynchronous method that executes the query asynchronously and returns a reader with:

```
var reader=await comm.ExecuteReaderAsync();
dt.Load(reader);
return dt;
```

After that, setting the `myDataTable` variable only requires using an `await`:

```
myDataTable = await GetDataTable(connectionString, commandText);
```

Comment: Cool!  As I said in my edit, I used the async counterparts of both `Open()` and `ExecuteReader()` and it seems to work out fine... I see you have used only `ExecuteReaderAsync()` - will there be a difference?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer you are looking for is here: [Async void exception handling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35312937/146900)

I'm assuming that the 'Button1_Click' method was meant to be 'async void'?:

```
private async void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Yep, I missed that one. It's meant to be async.